# How to get params by name in Roda/Rack when it's sent as "multipart/form-data"?

Tags: ruby, forms, parameters, roda

I have a Roda/Rack app. In a post handler this is data that I receive via a form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
An image -- binary data -- can be sent via it as well, that's why it's `multipart/form-data`

My code:

```
  r.body.rewind
  body_params = r.body.read
```

And it returns this:

```
  body_params

  => 
  "------WebKitFormBoundary123ABC\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
    name=\"utf8\"\r\n\r\n\xE2\x9C\x93\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary123ABC\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
    name=\"authenticity_token\"\r\n\r\n7/Q00bPqz5dKz7ktrlFMpK5mRMO/T8vwyDu1opc/3sdizUvEZrg6ECFSGUnLD4QcX3PHgj68l6k3Z9HTQE9/Jg==\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary123ABC\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
    name=\"model123[image_temp_url]\"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary123ABC\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
    name=\"model123[counterfoil_name]\"\r\n\r\nName:\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary123ABC\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
    name=\"model123[counterfoil_email]\"\r\n\r\nEmail:\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary123ABC\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
    name=\"model123[event_name]\"\r\n\r\ndasf\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary123ABC\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
    name=\"model123[event_date]\"\r\n\r\nfda\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary123ABC\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
    name=\"model123[description]\"\r\n\r\n              \r\n------WebKitFormBoundary123ABC\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
    name=\"model123[text_color]\"\r\n\r\n#000\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary123ABC\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
    name=\"model123[border_color]\"\r\n\r\n#cf2a27\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary123ABC\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
    name=\"model123[paper_size]\"\r\n\r\nA4\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary123ABC\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
    name=\"model123[font]\"\r\n\r\nArial\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary123ABC--\r\n"
```

Now, how can I parse params so that I can retrieve them by name, such as `body_params["model123"]["description"]`?

Answer (score 0):

Easy: just use `request.params` (or `r.params`):

```
2.5.0 :001 > body_params = r.body.tap(&:rewind).read
 => "-----------------------------17731730531088932352830400330\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
     name=\"model123[description]\"\r\n\r\nThis is the description.\r\n-----------------------------17731730531088932352830400330\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
     name=\"model123[font]\"\r\n\r\nComic Sans\r\n-----------------------------17731730531088932352830400330--\r\n"
2.5.0 :002 > r.params
 => {"model123"=>{"description"=>"This is the description.", "font"=>"This is something else."}}
2.5.0 :003 > request.params["model123"]["description"]
 => "This is the description."
```

The `#params` and the `#body` methods actually come from `Rack::Request`.  This is possible because Roda's request object, `Roda::RodaRequest`, [inherits from it](https://github.com/jeremyevans/roda/blob/3b907c84a93dde86c5ad5717dd9d2815625da80e/lib/roda.rb#L47).